# Asking a potential PI to visit his lab after succesful skype interview

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, computer-science

I couldn't find any threads here related to my particular situation, so I decided to ask here. Please guide me to a thread if you think it's already been answered!

So, last month I emailed a potential PI that I'm very excited to work with about openings in his group for a PhD position, and he emailed me back about setting up a skype call. I think the interview went well, and he asked me to let him know when I submit my application. He also talked about me with another professor in the same department, who also reached out to me for an interview, and I think that interview went well as well.

I submitted my application a little while later, and emailed both the professors that my app is in, and they said they will look at it soon, and also asked me to let them know if I got into any other programs, and they may be able to respond faster.

All of this sounds like positive news for me, but here's my question - I want to visit the group and see how the lab, and meet the PI in person once, but I don't know if they have the time to talk with me again, especially in person, since they have already interviewed me once before...

Any ideas on how to ask for a lab visit without sounding too imposing? (This school is in the U.S. for computer science PhD BTW...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to ask is just to ask. If you have any time parameters for when you'll be available then mention them. If they have the time and interest then they will likely respond. Otherwise they just might indicate it isn't possible at the moment. Note that people are likely busy at the moment with end of term approaching. And during the break may be more or less possible and more or less useful.

But just ask. Not a problem.

And, in CS, note that not everyone will have a "lab" as you might think of it. But you might be able to sit in on a meeting with other students.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Buffy. I was thinking along the same lines. I'll shoot him another email and hope for the best!